# error LNK2019 linking assimp

Tags: visual-c++, linker, assimp

I'm trying to get assimp samples to work in VC++ 2010 and I'm getting link errors.

http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/install.html

I set include and library directories up, copied the assimp.dll to System32 and put 'assimp.lib' to library dependencies.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiTransformVecByMatrix4 referenced in function _get_bounding_box_for_node
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiMultiplyMatrix4 referenced in function _get_bounding_box_for_node
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiIdentityMatrix4 referenced in function _get_bounding_box
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiTransposeMatrix4 referenced in function _recursive_render
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiImportFile referenced in function _loadasset
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiDetachAllLogStreams referenced in function _main
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiReleaseImport referenced in function _main
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiAttachLogStream referenced in function _main
1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiGetPredefinedLogStream referenced in function _main
1>Debug\SimpleOpenGL_Debug.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thank you, but I still have no idea what I'm doing wrong.I'm just trying to run the example so there should be no problem with the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Add lib files to `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` then add `assimp.lib` to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/3957606)